# Bearer token expiration in Social Tables

Tags: social-tables

Quick question, how long does a bearer token last in Social Tables before it expires and has to be refreshed? In other words, how often do we need to refresh the bearer token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our bearer tokens are valid for two weeks from the time issued.

Thanks.